# Normed and 2-normed spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Is every normed space a 2-normed space?

Again, is every 2-normed space a normed space?

please explain.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Every $2-$normed space is normed[1]. But $\mathbb{R}$ is normed space which is not $2-$normed. In fact for defining a $2-$normed space it is necessary that $dim X>1$.

[1]HENDRA GUNAWAN AND MASHADI, On finite dimensional 2-normed spaces,SOOCHOW JOURNAL OF MATHEMATICS,Volume 27, No. 3, pp. 321-329, July 2001